# UIScrollView, Autolayout and webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Can someone explain to me how `UIScrollView` and AutoLayout works? I'm trying to do the following:

`UIImageView` at the top
Under the `UIImageView` there's a label
Under the label there's a `UIWebView`

I managed to find out how I can modify the webview's height after the webview loaded (delegate and `webViewDidFinishLoad`), but I cannot figure out Auto Layouts.

It scrolls like charm, but cannot adapt the screen size and it happens only with `UIScrollView`, in a normal view the auto layout is no problem with this UI elements.

http://s10.postimg.org/4vl541e2x/K_perny_fot_2015_04_03_12_52_30.png
http://s10.postimg.org/nmn2e78nd/K_perny_fot_2015_04_03_12_53_36.png

Answer (score 0):

This might not be linked to Webview but to the ScrollView.

Basically, you need to manually setup a layout constraint between your parent view (the parent of the scroll view) and the content view (the children of the scroll view) that is probably the web view.

Be carefull to always add a single view to a scroll view, not multiple view.

Then in the view add the constraints manually, like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              relatedBy:0
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                               relatedBy:0
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
```

Where contentView is the scrollView children.

Look at this article for more info: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Some said that it could be possible by setting the same type of constraint in Builder, but I was not able to do it, while this works like a charm.